# How can you access a Storage Account blob container without using an Account Key?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How can you access a Storage Account blob container without using an Account Key?

I can access data in Storage Account blobs in Power BI ... **but it needs the account Access Key !**

Is there some way to access the data using some other authentication approach, i.e. an app registration, service principal, managed identity, whatever ?

Comment: If PowerBI can access Azure Key Vault, you could put the account key there which would shield the value from the user.

Comment: @JoelCochran Nice idea ... but how to get Power BI to access Key Vault?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is supported, but you can investigate here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-encryption-byok#:~:text=You%20enable%20BYOK%20at%20the%20tenant%20level%20with,Premium%20capacity%20for%20encrypting%20content%20in%20the%20capacity.

Comment: @JoelCochran Hmm ... that looks to be only around using Key Vault for data-at-rest encryption. Can't find anything about using Key Vault to get either a client secret or certificate for getting the OAuth access token :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Shared Access Signature(SAS)** to connect Blob Storage in Power BI. This [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chmitch/connecting-to-blob-storage-with-a-shared-access-signature-in-power-bi) will help you.

If you access blob with **Azure AD**, it doesn't seem to integrate with Power BI. And there is a [.Net code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#net-code-example-create-a-block-blob) about creating a block blob.

> Azure AD authenticates the security principal (a user,
> group, or service principal) running the application. If
> authentication succeeds, Azure AD returns the access token to the
> application, and the application can then use the access token to
> authorize requests to Azure Blob storage or Queue storage.

For more information, the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth) describes the options that Azure Storage offers for authorizing access to resources.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yeap, I can use the Power BI Web connector, and include the SAS token to get access to the data in the blob. Step forward as the SAS token only has Read and List permissions.